# how reflect changes in application after modifying values in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have moved user defined values present in web.config to database. I retrieve the values from database on appliction_start event of **global.cs** file and store those values in dictionary collection and will use throughout the application.

Now my problem is if I change any value in database the changes will is not reflected, to reflect the changes I have to reset the IIS. Hence to reflect the changes immediately or after a particular interval is there possibility like invoking the application_start event again or some other way.

please help....

Answer (score 0):

You could set up caching in your app and have the cache refreshed every X minutes, so you know that the values won't be more than X minutes old.

If they must be up-to-the-minute then you might store a "last modified" value in the database and check that each time before using the existing data, reloading if it's changed.

You might also be able to use the `SqlDependency` class to receive notification when the change occurs but I've never done it so I don't know the details.

Answer (score 0):

you can restart IIS. open command line and type:

```
iisreset
```

OR

restart the application which could be done with IIS Manager or manually with web config change (add a new empty line to the web config)

Other solutions:

- refresh the dictionary pragmatically from your application
- does not load these values on application start but use asp.net cache with sql dependency to detect changes in the DB.